# Represent a 2D list as a map of colored squares in Pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say I have a 2D list that looks like this:

```
[
['Red','Green','Blue'],
['Red','Red','Green'],
['Red','Red','Red' ]
                   ]
```

Is there a way I could represent it in Pylab as an map with squares actually being of the color given in a 2D list?

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can convert your 2D list as a list of numbers, then you can use the imshow function in python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.array(((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)))
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

you will need the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) packages for this.

Comment: This is not exactly what I asked for, but it does fit my needs fine, in some way even better. Thank You.